# Extraer datos de Internet Explorer a Excel

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

Buen dia.
Estoy programando una macro que extraer información de una Tabla en Internet Explorer y la carga a una hoja de Excel.

Hasta ahora solo he logrado extraer los encabezados de la tabla pero no he logrado obtener el contenido.

```
    Sub extraerDatos()

    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim TDelements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim TDelement As HTMLTableCell
    Dim oElement As Object
    Dim r As Long


    URL = "URL"

    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

    With IE
        .Navigate URL
        .Visible = True

        'Cargar pagina
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

        Set HTMLdoc = .Document
    End With
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

Set dados = HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("tableContainer")
 (0).getElementsByTagName("span")
    I = 0
 For Each oElement In dados
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A" & I + 1) = dados(I).innerText
    I = I + 1
 Next oElement
End Sub
```

Este es el codigo HTML de donde quiero obtener los datos.

```
<div class="tableContainer"  >
        <div class="tlnTable tlnw12" id="tlnAngTableTransfers" style="display:none" >
            <span style="margin:0; padding-bottom: 10px;" class="field-validation-error ng-binding" ng-show="model.bTransferRequired">Select at least one transfer</span>
            <div class="tlnHeader tlnw12"> <!-- HEADER -->
                <div class="tlnw3">
                    <div class="tlnw1 tlntd">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="model.grid.selected" ng-change="model.grid.selectAll()"/> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="tlnw6 tlntd">
                        <a href="#" class="tlnSortLink tlnw12" ng-click="model.grid.sortableColumns.columns.transferId.changeSort()">
                            <span class="tlnw10">Transfer ID / PO-SO Number </span>
                            <span class="tlnSortIco tlnw2" ng-show="model.grid.sortableColumns.lastSortedColumn.id === model.grid.sortableColumns.columns.transferId.id" >
                                <span class="tlnSortAsc tlnw12 " ng-class="{act: model.grid.sortableColumns.lastSortedColumn.modifier==='asc', inact: model.grid.sortableColumns.lastSortedColumn.modifier==='desc'}" ></span>
                                <span class="tlnSortDesc inact tlnw12" ng-class="{act: model.grid.sortableColumns.lastSortedColumn.modifier==='desc', inact: model.grid.sortableColumns.lastSortedColumn.modifier==='asc'}"></span>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
```

Entenderia que la clave esta en la parte de NG pero desconosco como obtener estos datos.
Espero que me puedan ayudar. Gracias

Comment: bienvenido/a hdan7, lo que quieres es que mediante una macro en excel, puedas extraer datos de una página web y dichos datos colocarlos en una celda en particular. ¿Es esto correcto? ¿Del HTML que muestras, cuál es el contenido que esperas extraer?Con el código mostrado, ¿Qué error te genera? Saludos

Comment: Hola Fredyfx, Si tengo una aplicación en intranet, que me arroja una tabla con datos. Cuando ingreso a la URL en automático se me genera latabla con información. Quiero obtener todo ese contenido en Excel, el codigo que mostre me conecta a la pagina pero solo me extrae los titulos de la tabla

Comment: podrías especificar cuál es el contenido que deseas extraer por favor :D